# Why TRUE not given to function in class

Tags: php, function, oop, if-statement, boolean

I have some issues with my large project. I can't figure out why giving TRUE to a function does not produce the expected result.

I have:

```
class Cat
{
    final public function abc ($a = FALSE) // UPD: Forgot this is final
    {
        var_dump($a); // <---- WHY FALSE?
        if ($a)
        {
            print('YES');
        }
        else
        {
            print('NO');
        }
    }

    private function meow ()
    {
        $blabla = $this->abc(TRUE);
        //some code
    }
}
```

It always prints NO, but i need YES.

But this example in online redactor prints YES:

```
function abc ($a = FALSE)
{
    if ($a)
    {
        print('YES');
    }
    else
    {
        print('NO');
    }
}

abc(TRUE);
```

**UPD:** Maybe my first example ( my code) not working because is not over - riding that variable?
**UPD-1:** If var_dump $a it show boolean false. Why?

Comment: Can't reproduce the error! Please show us how you call/create your objects and methods! (BTW: Your method is private so you can't call it from outside)

Comment: Surely that is correct behaviour? As by default you're passing in `$a = FALSE` into the first example and in the second example over-riding that with `abc(TRUE)`?

Comment: How to over-ride FALSE in first example?

Comment: Please add at the beginning `var_dump($a);` of function `abc`.

Comment: Yes it tested that value $a is false...But now question is why is that?

Comment: your method is private. How are you calling it? From within the class?

Comment: there are two problems in your code one meow method is private second abc is not returning any thing, its just printing. If you are not doing any kind of strict checking then you wont be able to test for false. You need to check in your code like this $blabla === false. and add a return statement in your abc method.

Comment: Yes from the class. amrhady

Comment: Show the code that you're using to call it - to call the meow function.